# Can datetime parse this format of time string?

Tags: python, datetime

My original time string is in this format:

```
2017-01-22 13:54:55
```

But in excel after opening the file, the date format becomes:

```
01/22/17 13:54:55
```

I tried to parse it in this way:

```
 try:
                return dt.strptime('01/22/17 13:54:55', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            except Exception as e:
                try:
                    return dt.strptime('01/22/17 13:54:55', '%-m/%-d/%y %H:%M:%S')
                except Exception as e:
                    raise ValueError('Reference time must be the format of: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, or a datetime object')
```

Is there a way to parse "01/22/17 13:54:55" by the strptime function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, remove the `-` instead:

```
dt.strptime('01/22/17 13:54:55', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```